# Extracing SQL Service Broker Error Fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, service-broker

I am creating some error handling for the `'SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'` `MessageType` within my queues `Activation Stored Procedure`.  While, I have information on how to access the following exception fields:

- Code (e.g. Error Number)
- Description (e.g. Error Message)

I am having trouble finding information on how to access (other) 'standard' error fields from the 'SQL/ServiceBroker/Error' schema, fields like:

```
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
DECLARE @ErrorProcedure VARCHAR(400);
DECLARE @ErrorLine INT;
```

...I am having trouble finding information on.

Does anyone know...

- Where I can get information of the access these fields from the
  'SQL/ServiceBroker/Error' schema?

FOR EXAMPLE:
For those who need to see code ...

```
---------------
-- HANDLE ERRORS: for Error MessageTypes
---------------
ELSE IF @MessageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'
BEGIN

   -- GET ERROR: Alias Namespace
   WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error' AS ssb)
   SELECT 
          @ErrorNumber = @MessageBody.value('(//ssb:Error/ssb:Code)[1]', 'INT'),
          @ErrorMessage = @MessageBody.value('(//ssb:Error/ssb:Description)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');
          --@ErrorSeverity = ????,
          --@ErrorState = ????,
          --@ErrorProcedure = ????,
          --@ErrorLine = ????;

    -- CLOSE CONVERSATION
    END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
END
```

Comment: One thing I like to do in a similar situation (in my case, when the activation procedure has an error processing a message) is to preserve the unaltered message in a table somewhere for further investigation. Parse out what you can but don't rely on that and give yourself a chance to diagnose the problem by having the message as generated by the system available as well.